# History of VB.NET Nullable syntax

Tags: vb.net, syntax, nullable

I can't find a definitive answer.  Since C# 2.0 you've been able to declare

```
int? i = 125;
```

as shorthand for

```
Nullable<int> i = Nullable<int>(123);
```

I recall reading somewhere that VB.NET did not allow this shortcut.  But low and behold, I tried it in VS 2008 today and it works.

Does anyone know whether it's been this way since .NET 2.0 or was this added later?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

System.Nullable was introduced in .Net 2.0 and is available to VB *as a generic type*.  You just cannot use the nullable syntax.  So in VS 2005 you can do:

```
Dim x as Nullable(of Integer)
```

I don't know if null equivalence and boxing works for nullables in VB 2005, but I would suspect that the answer is yes since the .Net team made a change to the 2.0 CLR to accomplish boxing with nullables.  I would imagine VB leverages this.

In 2008, you can obviously just do:

```
Dim x as Integer?
```

Comment: The null equivalence and boxing worked in VB 2005. The changes in 2008 focused on adding the "?" syntax, and implementing operator lifting. One thing to note, though, is that support for the "?" syntax was not added to the VS Code Model / Code DOM, so any designer generated code that uses nullable types will always use the old generic syntax.

Answer (score 3):

it works in VB 2005 (dotnet 2.0) but it's ugly.

You can't use it like a normal variable, I thought it might work like an Object type but it doesn't.

Rather than this:

```
dim oInt as object

dim i as integer

if oInt is nothing then 

    msgbox("int is null")
else

    i = cint(oInt)

end if
```

you have this.

```
Dim oInt as nullable(of integer)

dim i as integer

if oInt.HasValue = false then 

    msgbox("int is null")

else

   i = oInt.Value

end if
```

The problem here is that if your variable is null and you happen to invoke the Value property it barfs up an unhandled exception.

so for instance, my favorite one is this.

```
AddParamToSQLCmd(sqlCmd, "@SomeID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, iif(oInt.HasValue, oInt.Value, DBNull.value))
```

Will result in an runtime error when your Supposed Nullable value is null!!!

so here's nullable(of integer) vs Object code

nullable(of integer)

```
if oInt.HasValue then 
    AddParamToSQLCmd(sqlCmd, "@SomeID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, oInt.Value)
else
    AddParamToSQLCmd(sqlCmd, "@SomeID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, dbnull.value)
end if
```

Object

```
AddParamToSQLCmd(sqlCmd, "@SomeID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, oInt)
```

Comment: A simpler way of adding the parameter would be to make use of the 'new' 'If' operator: 

AddParamToSQLCmd(sqlCmd, "@SomeID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, If(oInt.HasValue, oInt.Value, DBNull.value)) 

The reason that the above works is that If is a ahort-circuit operator whereas both sides of an IIf method call are evaluated, regardless of if the first operand evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, nullable types were introduced in .NET 2.0 at a very late stage. The C# compiler team managed to cram in more language support for them than the VB.NET team did. The VB.NET team more or less caught up in VS2008. That's why you can, for example, use the == operator to compare nullables in C# 2.0 whereas in VB.NET you had to put up with the Nullable.Equals() method. Grrr.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the history, but yes it was a VS 2008 enhancement.