# Make A Date Null

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can someone help me fix my code I am trying to put null in sql server through a function that is excepting _dtSWO.

If I set _dtSWO = Nothing it returns #12:00:00 AM# which throws an exception. The field is nullable in sql server I just want it to return a blank

```
Dim _swoDate As String = udSWOReceivedDateDateEdit.Text
        Dim _dtSWO As Date

        If _swoDate <> "" Then
            _dtSWO = Date.Parse(udSWOReceivedDateDateEdit.Text)
        Else
            'THIS DOESNT WORK
            _dtSWO = Nothing
        End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a Nullable type.  By default, Date does not except null (Nothing in VB.Net) as a value.  [Nullable types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2004/05/28/143813.aspx) do accept null (Nothing).

```
    Dim _dtSWO As Nullable(Of Date)

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_swoDate) Then
        _dtSWO = Date.Parse(udSWOReceivedDateDateEdit.Text)
    Else
        _dtSWO = Nothing
    End If
```

Edited based on the comment.

Comment: You may also want to catch the null string case; instead of comparing against an empty string literal, I'd use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Answer (score 1):

Make it Nullable.  Same kind of situation as your Nullable Integer question.

```
Dim _swoDate As String = udSWOReceivedDateDateEdit.Text
Dim _dtSWO As Date?

If _swoDate <> "" Then
    _dtSWO = Date.Parse(udSWOReceivedDateDateEdit.Text)
Else
    _dtSWO = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: The question mark is shorthand.  Works in VB.NET although I generally don't see it used in many VB.NET examples online.

Comment: It was not valid syntax at first, but was added later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223844/history-of-vb-net-nullable-syntax

Comment: I believe when nullable types were first introduced the `?` was not available in VB. However, at some point that ability was added.