# Using Nulls in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, api, hp-quality-center

I am calling the OTA API from HP Quality Centre and one of the calls requires sending a NULL.

This is the actual line of code:

```
stepF.AddItem(NULL)
```

This works perfectly in VBA and VB6 but VB.NET doesn't accept Nulls. Anyone know how to fix such an issue?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `Nothing`, which is [mostly equivalent](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/nothing-vs-null.html) to `null`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'd already tried that and it results in an error stating that "Value does not fall within the expected range".

Answer (score 2):

`Nothing` is the Null value for most reference types in VB.Net,  I would recommend taking a look at `Nullable(Of T)` on either [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) or some good information about it in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223844/history-of-vb-net-nullable-syntax), if the API you are using is a .Net web service you may be able to partial class the WSDL and fix although it sounds as though you are not.

Comment: Actually, it's a COM api, not a web service.

Answer (score 2):

The correct value to use is `System.DBNull.Value`.

Even if the documentation tells us that this is generally used for database null values, it represent the absence of value, otherwise `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx?ppud=4)